# Stream with Wowza over SSL, Connection Refused or invalid response

Tags: ssl, wowza

I installed Wowza and is Streaming by this links:

**HTTP:**

> http ://[my-ip]:1935/myapp/*definst*/mp4:00.Intro.mp4/manifest.mpd

and also on

> http ://[my-subdomain]:1935/myapp/*definst*/mp4:00.Intro.mp4/manifest.mpd

When is config Wowza to be able to stream on port 80, it works again on these links:

> http ://[my-ip]/myapp/*definst*/mp4:00.Intro.mp4/manifest.mpd
>
> http ://[my-subdomain]/myapp/*definst*/mp4:00.Intro.mp4/manifest.mpd

but we must stream over SSL protocol.

means: **HTTPS:**

> https ://[my-subdomain]/myapp/*definst*/mp4:00.Intro.mp4/manifest.mpd

We installed a wildcard SSL on our server and everything is working great. In general, port 1935 does not work over **HTTPS**! even when we add port 80 to Wowza, **HTTPS connection is refused** and we can't have streaming over https.

How can we stream over SSL on wowza? even with or without port 1935

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Wowza server supports streaming with SSL using [StreamLock](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?454-How-to-get-SSL-certificates-from-the-StreamLock-service) or your own SSL certificate.

You will need to set up a different port number for HTTPS. It could be that another process is using port 80. Port 443 is typically used.

1. From the **Server** tab, click Edit.
2. Click **Add Host Port** and fill in fields.
3. Check **Enable SSL/StreamLock**.
4. Save and re-start Wowza server.

Look in [install-dir]/logs/wowzastreamingengine_access.log for errors. It will give a clue as to whether there is a problem with the certificate, password or other.

Comment: We must install our Certificate as a jsk to be able to enable SSL/StreamLock.

Comment: Also you can add some additional [error logging](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?732-How-to-improve-SSL-configuration#config) to better help identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was recommend place a LB infront of my Wowza for SSL offloading so you can load the m3u8 over SSL. I was also told you can do that quite easily using HA Proxy for example. It is explained how to accomplish this here for RTMP but the same can obviously done with HTTP:

https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/457#issuecomment-250783255

Note, I have not tried this yet and I am unclear on exactly the proper use scenario. Nor, have I successfully enable StreamLock with my own cert nor the cert provided through Wowza. If I manage to do so I will update this thread. Hope this is helpful.